# Sass --watch only compiling initially

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I have Sass v 3.3.6 installed on a ruby project.  I'm running the command:

```
sass --watch assets/sass/
```

which upon running, compiles the sass files in the sass folder into css files in the folder.  However, if I make any changes to the sass files without re-running the above command, the css files don't update.  I thought that the `--watch` command auto-updated upon changes.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just checking, does it run fine without you specifying an output dir like: `sass --watch input_dir:output_dir`?

Comment: I'll try, but my input dir is the same as my output

Comment: No it doesn't work, just tried it.

Comment: just thought I'd check since that's the syntax I'm used to using, and hadn't tried without an output_dir. I think it should do as you expect, does it work if you have a separate output_dir? (just asking as it works fine for me in those circumstances).

Comment: No still not working... just tried this. `sass --watch assets/sass/:assets/css/`  Only compiles upon  the first time running.

Comment: are you on linux, do you know if you have hit your limit of inotify watchers? try `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` if it doesn't work then you need to increase your `inotify.max_user_watchers`

Comment: what system are you on?

Comment: OSX Mavericks,it's just a simple rails project, no compass, just Purecss and Sass

Comment: well the equivalent of inotify on mac is fsevent, you could check if there's a problem with that, unfortunately I don't know it well, good luck.